# Accessing root DOM element of a component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the [vue-textarea-autosize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-textarea-autosize) plugin on a textarea so as more content is added, it automatically resizes.

The problem is, if the user presses enter, it creates a new line. But, I want enter to be treated as 'process this' and call an event handler instead.

I tried setting `@keydown.enter.exact.prevent` and `@keyup.enter.exact = processCommand()` on the element:

```
<textarea-autosize
                    @keydown.enter.exact.prevent
                    @keyup.enter.exact = processCommand
            />
```

But the problem is, I can't access the DOM `textarea` itself since its within `textarea-autosize`. Changing this to a normal textarea works.

Is there a workaround for this, or a way to expose the dom element from within the component?

Comment: Have you tried `.native`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Thanks, that was it! Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to listen to a native event on the root element of a component you can use the `.native` event modifier:

```
<textarea-autosize
    @keydown.enter.native="processCommand"
/>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Listening-for-Native-Events-on-Components-with-v-on-changed